# SQL Server overwriting a View PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, view

I have an ajax call that results in a view being created in my SQL Database. Is there a way to overwrite the existing view in the database.

I basically want to insert what the user selects into the view. And everytime this happens, the whole view is overwritten.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: You can overwrite the view with "alter view view_name_here as select field1, field2... from yourtable where ..." command -- so most of it depends on what you actually need to have there.

Comment: yes, alter view definitely works. Wonder why I never though of it. Thanks alot

Comment: have you tried with an "ALTER VIEW AS .... " statement?